# Data not fetch from vehicle tracking device

Tags: c#, asp.net, tcp, tcpclient

```
 if ((tcpClient.Connected == true))
                {
                    int clientCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref clients);

                    NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();

                    //Console.WriteLine("Client connected. ({0} connected)", clientCount);


                    StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();


                    if (clientStream.CanRead)
                    {
                        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];

                        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

                        // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.

                        try
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                numberOfBytesRead = clientStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

                                myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));

                            }
                            while (clientStream.DataAvailable);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            tcpClient.Close();

                        }

                    }
                    }
```

I am working on vehicle Tracking System. I did this code as listner
    I try to read data from vehicle tracking device i get data when i send through client(local machine/PC) but it cant read data from device
Thanks

Comment: What device are you using?  What error message are you getting?  Is the Device sending ASCII or UTF8? Do you have to send a command to device before receiving data?  Did you turn on the device?  I have 1000 more questions but there isn't enough space in this comment to ask all the questions!!!

Comment: device send this type of frame 

nt:865067020721174;2;8.5.03;1,1,20160624085251.000,18.581017,73.816858,214.500,0.24,120.6,;50;010;0;0;0;FF;08;9

Comment: yes i send command to device and set my IP and port

Comment: You are fetching the correct data.  See my solution on following webpage.  If you need more help let me know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931866/convert-gps-position-from-double-value.  Without knowing model number of device I can't give better answer.

Comment: thanks for quick replay
when i send data from my pc i got that string in database but when it come from device i get empty data

Comment: Thanks jdweng your info help me lot now get that sting but currently problem is that i written this code in asp.net webpage start going to continus loop but after 6 minute it close and get erro [HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]

Comment: Turn on KeepAlive : tcpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

Comment: but i get error of webpages its timeout.  i try to make server on webpage.
after some period url get stoped

Comment: Right now I'm confused with your code and comments.  The GPS device is a Server app for TCP and your webpage is the client.  The webpage can still be a SERVER app for Http.  So I'm not sure if the TCP isw timing out or the Http is timing out.The GPS device may just be going to sleep.Normally TCP Server will disconnect is no messages are received for a period of time.The keepAlive option for a client will periodically send an empty data packet to keep the server from shutting down.You are getting an HttpException which probably means you need to set the keepalive on the http as well as the TCP.

Comment: I am new for this consent so what i want to do for making tcp server in c#

Comment: You should be using the a Client application like the one(s) at msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I write tcp server code in winform how i host this code on remote server

Comment: Does that make sense?  If you are in NYC do you want the GPS location of a server in Los Angeles?

Comment: is that correct written server code in windows application ?
or any other ways cause i get confused while publishing on remote server
someone told me use wcf and dont know correct way

Comment: The GPS device is a server and the PC connected to the device is a client.  The client PC can be connected to a network and either be a client or a server.  I can't tell from your requirements what your network requirements are for the Client PC.

Comment: in my case device is client while pc is server